# Is it OK to (self-) answer if you're only 99% sure of your answer?

Tags: discussion

I had a problem. I solved it, but I was worried there might be holes in the solution that I hadn't considered.

So I thought I'd post the question to Stack Overflow, and I saw two choices.

1. Post my code and ask "is this ok?", or
2. post the original problem as a question, and use self-answer mechanism to post my solution as an answer, to go into the pot with potential other answers, be up/downvoted as normal, perhaps critiqued in comments...

I decided 2 was a better option, as (I felt) it really wasn't a simple yes/no question, but rather a question of how best to solve the original problem.

I got one constructive comment on my answer, then a couple of comments saying I wasn't answering the question (which I believe I was, although I did finish with "Is this secure? Is this overkill?", which may have raised alarm bells).

And then shortly afterwards, my answer was simply deleted. This seemed a bit harsh, and when I read https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers I'm not really sure which of the reasons were the grounds for deletion - only real candidates were "not attempting to answer the question", which I just flat-out don't accept, and "asking another, different question", which I don't think I agree with either, but makes slightly more sense.

So my question is: was this an appropriate use of the self-answer mechanism, or should I have just posted the "is this ok?" question? If I hadn't questioned the correctness of my own answer but simply posted it as a solution would that have been better? And was it correct for someone to *delete* the answer in the circumstances?

Full disclosure: there's a further wrinkle. The question probably doesn't belong on Stack Overflow in the first place - it was pointed out that being more about cryptography algorithms, it should instead be on security.stackexchange instead, and I tend to agree.

So, given that and that my answer had been deleted, I decided to delete the question. But if you ignore the off-topic part of the problem, the question above still applies. Deleted question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809412/cryptographically-secure-end-to-end-over-http - let me know if I should undelete it for reference purposes.

Comment: It would be awesome if every answerer is at least 99% sure …

Comment: If I'm 99.5% sure should I round down or up?

Comment: @GeorgeReith depends [which rounding methodology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Rounding_to_integer) you're using :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, in general, if you're unsure of what you have that could otherwise be a potential solution, you should include it in your question instead as an attempt at solving your problem, where your requests for feedback and confirmation would be more appropriate (although given the specific questions you asked somebody might deem your question more suited to Code Review than here). Use the self-answer mechanism only when you're proposing it as a (or the) definitive answer to your question (while still subjecting it to votes, comments and other feedback).

See also [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199834/should-own-solution-be-included-within-the-question/199835#199835) to a similar question on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm probably selling my solution short above. I definitely wouldn't say I was "unsure" - I believed (and still do) that I had solved the problem. But being crypto, if you think you've built a 100% secure solution, you're wrong. And I guess I just didn't want to be saying "hey look at my fantastic solution" only to have some crypto expert to slam me down and laugh at my puny understanding of *real* crypto. So I probably should have just left out the auxiliary questions. And posted to the right site.

Comment: @CupawnTae: I would say there is always a chance you might be wrong anyway... personally I self-answer but do not accept for a while, it gives time for others to answer and maybe show there is a better way :)

Answer (score 12):

Your answer, as phrased, really sounds like a continuation of the question.

One guideline for self-answering questions might be — can someone read the question and the answer, not realize that they're by the same person, and have it still make sense as a question and answer? And in the example you link to, that doesn't seem to be the case.

To fix this, I think you can remove this sentence from your question:

> I'm also going to post my proposed solution as an answer, please feel free to critique/tear it apart, and if there's a better solution presented, I'll gladly accept it.

(perhaps moving it to a comment), and change the framing of your answer from this:

> Here's the algorithm we're proposing: [… answer …] Is this secure? Is it overkill?

to this:

> This may be overkill, and actually I'm not 100% sure if it's secure, but here's one algorithm you can try: [… answer …]

And presented like that, of course, you can see that it's not a very good answer. I mean, it's good to be explicit that you're unsure of its security, rather than just blithely asserting that it's secure, but given that the OP will not be able to *test* the security of the algorithm, an answer that can't assert its security is almost not an answer at all.

Comment: Good points, although now I'm starting to feel defensive about my answer :) I'm actually pretty confident that it's secure, but wars have been lost because people believed their cryptography was secure when it wasn't, and it is a well-accepted rule of crypto that to really validate the security of an algorithm, you have to publish it and have it scrutinized by experts. However, I have to accept that attempting to both solicit new solutions to the original problem, and at the same time have my own solution validated didn't really fit the self-answer format, and also the topic didn't fit SO.

Comment: @CupawnTae: Even if the algorithm is secure, and even if you're *pretty* confident that it's secure, the answer is only as useful as the asker is confident in trusting it. In this case, if the asker were not you, I would expect him/her to be a bit dubious. Upvotes and comments can help with that, of course. (That said -- I don't think it's a *bad* answer. I just don't think it's a *very good* answer, either.)

Comment: Ok, so that's about the quality of the *answer*, as opposed to the quality of the *solution* I guess? An important distinction, and again I guess I have to agree - as would be the case for any answer that doesn't explain *why* it's theoretically secure. I also probably have to work on my phrasing of things... I think I probably say things like "actually pretty confident" when other people would be swearing on their mother's life.

Comment: @CupawnTae: I don't think you "have to work on [your] phrasing of things". Other people may be too quick to swear on their mothers' lives, but that doesn't mean you should ape them. It's clear that you are not confident enough in your solution to simply declare that it *is* a solution, but then you want the rest of us to understand that you're really, really close to being confident enough, and to act as though that were the same as actually knowing for sure. Unsurprisingly, we're not really willing to do that.

Comment: @CupawnTae: And as for the solution itself . . . do you have any response to the potential problem that Iridium pointed out?

Comment: As for Iridium's problem, yes, a simple solution is for the server to sign the response (and on re-reading I notice Iridium already suggested it) - this isn't really necessary in my case as the attack would just break the subsequent interactions rather than allowing unauthorized access. I would have upvoted and replied to Iridium's point but by the time I read it the answer had been deleted and so I couldn't. However, I already intended to include that aspect next time (if there is one)

Comment: ...but turns out there's a more fundamental flaw that I don't currently have an answer for. Glad I left that 1% doubt in there ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you have a solution, and it works then post it and let the community do it's work, if someone has something better to offer or disagrees with it chances are they will post it.

If you know it has adverse effects then state that.

The premise of this question is too flawed, no one is ever 100% certain of an answer (whether they feel it or not), you only know what you think you know. Donald Rumsfeld puts this nicely:

> ... there are known knowns; there are things that we know that we know. We also know there are known unknowns; that is to say we know there are some things we do not know. But there are also unknown unknowns, the ones we don't know we don't know.

[Source](http://www.defense.gov/transcripts/transcript.aspx?transcriptid=2636)

Comment: except I did, and the community deleted my answer rather than vote on it. But I think a lot of that was to do with how I worded it

Answer (score 2):

I think you should self-answer even if you're not sure at all, but you want to post the code/action that fixes your problem. Even if you are actually mistaken, the worst thing is that someone will come across and say "You did wrong, you should do that and that", and you probably can do the same and assess the added value, probably accepting that one as "the" answer.

Comment: that's an interesting approach - I'd imagine a lot of people would disagree. But no, the worst thing is not that someone would critique it, in fact I openly invited that in my question *and* answer (which was apparently a mistake). The worst thing is that someone with enough rep would come along and summarily delete the answer, which is what happened.

Comment: @CupawnTae your answer was diamond-mod-deleted, probably in response to a Not An Answer flag. Personally I'd disagree with that call, but mods have a *lot* of work to do and thus have a limited time they can spend on each and every decision.

Comment: @AakashM Understood, in fact what you're saying is exactly what I strongly suspected from the start. And while I'm sure I come across as moaning and banging on about the deletion, I was genuinely asking whether it was the right call, as I don't have enough experience here to make a definite statement either way. Anyway, in my comment on *this* answer I was just saying that no, the worst thing that can happen is *not* someone pointing out flaws in the answer - there are worse outcomes.