# Answering my own question, while not fully sure about the answer, if there is no other answers at all?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37434702/fine-uploader-with-rails-form) is a question I've asked.

Here's the background:

I'm asking a question, and not getting any answer. Before I've asked a question, I've been looking for some tutorials or anything. No success. If you read the comments, you will know, that there might be none of those. So, left without a choice, I'm starting to experiment on my own, and eventually figuring some solution out. I'm not sure about it, and I know that there might be a better solution (I mean, a specific solution that I've simple didn't try). Because of that, it seems like I shouldn't post an answer. But in that case, chances of getting a high quality answer are really low. I don't want to provide an answer that may point someone in the wrong direction, but also I wouldn't like to keep the knowledge I've got only for myself(especially, when it seems that it is difficult to find ANY answer).
So:

- Should I post that answer, even if it maybe not perfect, but it might be the only help someone will get, when having the same problem?
- If yes, should I mark it as a correct answer, or rather just leave it there, and wait until someone post something better? (even if it means not accepting any answer till the end of times)

Comment: Related [question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256191/is-it-ok-to-self-answer-if-youre-only-99-sure-of-your-answer?rq=1).

Comment: Realistically it sounds the answer should be "don't use dead projects unless you really have to". I'm not really sure how useful your effort to write good answer will be - possibly if you plan to revive the project you are using effort may pay off eventually. (otherwise answer by sr28 covers steps in general, may consider bounty when/if have extr rep).

Comment: It seems like [Cunningham's Law](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cunningham%27s_Law) doesn't apply on StackExchange sites. Questions with any answer at all are less likely to draw in people who can provide the most correct answer.

Comment: Zeb you're worrying about *nothing*.  It's just an internet site.  In 15 years it will be dust.  Go ahead an click "Post".  All information is valuable, there's no reason you "wouldn't do it".

Comment: Mark it as correct answer if it solved your problem but do not mark it if it didn't. Anyway, you can change the correct answer marking at any time later, should there be a better (more complete) answer.

Comment: When you have some rep to spare, you would be able to post a bounty on your question and that *may* attract some attention.  I have approximately 50/50 experience.

Comment: Perhaps you'd get an answer if you'd ask a better question.  It's unclear what you're asking.  "I don't seem to understand how this thing actually works" isn't a question.  "Also, templating does not work, I don't really understands why." isn't a question either, and if I'd interpret it as a question, you're not being specific (errors?). Finally, "I'm open for changing this library to something else" isn't a question either and if I'd again interpret it as a question, it's asking for an advise for a library which is off-topic as per the help center.

Comment: @JoeBlow: You're implying that SE has no rules or content policies just because it's on the internet and won't last forever. You are mistaken.

Comment: Hi @Lights. I never imply anything.  The five sentences in my comment above are exact.  They apply to the case at hand.

Comment: @Arjan - I didn't look at it like that. But now I think you are right, and I'll update my answer, but in that case, it may not help. You are right nonetheless. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: Ok, I've added the answer. Thanks everyone for opinions.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

[**Please** post your solution!](https://xkcd.com/979/)

### [image: All long help threads should have a sticky globally-editable post at the top saying 'DEAR PEOPLE FROM THE FUTURE: Here's what we've figured out so far ...']

Yes, if you figured out *anything* that solves your problem, that's by definition a solution, and worth an answer. Even if it might not be the best answer, it is much better than no answer. If it really was a bad answer, and there would be superior ones, they would get posted and voted upon accordingly.

You might want to add a disclaimer to your answer that the solution was only found by (clueless) experimentation and that you are no expert on the topic if you are really unsure.

Answer (score 23):

I think if you've found something that works and answers your own question then it's fine to add it as the answer, but be sure to put in any limitations or assumptions your answer has. Ultimately, this will hopefully be of some help to others, and failing that it may well help you if others post something that may be wrong with your own answer, which you may not have thought of.

See '[How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)', specifically:

> **Have the same problem?**
>
> Still no answer to the question, and you have the same problem? Help
>   us find a solution by researching the problem, then **contribute the
>   results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a
>   partial answer**. That way, even if we can’t figure it out, the next
>   person has more to go on.

I've highlighted the part about contributing a partial answer, as if nothing else it could help point others in the right direction. If it was me and I was particularly concerned that what I put might be incorrect or misleading I'd leave it for a few days before accepting it as the answer, therefore giving others enough time to comment on why it may not perhaps be a suitable answer.

Answer (score 2):

YES, definitely answer your own question in the "[good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)" style, caveats and all. I don't expect your answer to be completely correct for my situation. This is an iterative process, and we all know it (or should). The bits and pieces of your imperfect answer can give me the clue to solve my problem, and that's what I really need.

Answer (score 2):

Even an imperfect answer can help someone with the same problem, that's for sure-- especially if you're upfront on the caveats and limitations of what you found out.

If you are concerned that answering your own questions will deter others from providing better answers: You can always **provide a self-answer but not accept it,** since you feel that it is only a partial solution to the question.

I should add that seeing a confused or misguided answer to a question has often spurred me to provide a better one. So don't worry about your efforts deterring new answers.

Answer (score 0):

you should not hesitate in posting an answer if and only if it has solved your problem. Better answer are going to come even though, and people will vote to the answers which suits them most. But till the time no body else has answered a better answer, if a person is going through the same problem, at least he will have a solution which has already worked for somebody else, and that is the purpose of this community.